# How to read HTML tags

Tags: javascript, html

I want to read the HTML tags with Javascript without using id/class. I know about the functionality of ***getElementById***. But I want to know how to read HTML tags without using id or class in Javascript and not by Jquery.

Comment: What do you mean by read? What's with all the random restrictions? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName

Comment: This moz docs might be helpful to you as well: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/intro.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The entire DOM API is there for you.

- `(element).getElementsByTagName` gets elements by tag name.
- `(element).getElementsByClassName` gets elements by class name.
- `(element).querySelector[All]` gets an element/elements based on a CSS selector.
- `(element).children` gets an element's child elements.
- `(element).childNodes` gets an element's child nodes.

The list goes on and on.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`document.getElementsByTagName(...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByTagName), for example:

```javascript
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
divs; // => a list of "div" elements in the document.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `document.getElementsByTagName`.

```
    var allDivsinDom = document.getElementsByTagName('div'); //Array of all divs
    var allAnchorinDom = document.getElementsByTagName('a'); //Array of all a
....
```

this way you can access all elements in dom

Answer (score 0):

You can also get `document.body.childNodes` and `childNodes` of every child node and read whole DOM tree, like here:

```
function readHTML(node) {
    var i, child;
    if (node.nodeType == 1) { // only tags 
        for (i = 0 ; i < node.childNodes.length ; ++i) {
            child = node.childNodes[i];
            // do something with node
            window.console.info(child.tagName);
            readHTML(child);
        }
    }
}
readHTML(document.body);
```

as well as `document.getElementsByTagName` proposed before

Answer (score 0):

The HTML tags in a page form a tree; the root of that tree is a node called 'document'. You can call methods on that node, such as getElementById, to find nodes further in the tree, but you don't have to.

You can retrieve the raw HTML contents of any node, including the entire document, by accessing its innerHTML property. (note that that doesn't give you the HTML tag of the node itself, but of its contents, so you need to get the node's parent's innerHTML if you need that tag as well)

If you want to read the raw HTML of the entire document, then, try accessing document.documentElement.innerHTML, and parsing what you get back from that.

Comment: document.innerHTML is property, not a function. document.innerHTML() will rise exception